# load next previous html page with java script

Tags: java, javascript, html

I'm making a website containing a book and the user should have the option to go to the next or previous chapter. Each chapter has 1 html file. I'm already using this script, but when I press the next or previous button, [enter link description here](http://www.domain.com/book/NaN.html) tries to load this page rather than 2.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function goto(url) { window.location=url; } 
var curPage = parseInt(location.href.replace(/([1-93]+)\.html/, ''))
if (curPage <= 1) {
// First page, no 'back' link
document.write('<a href="#" class="disabled">Back</a>');
} else {
var backPage = curPage-1;
document.write("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"goto('"+backPage+".html')\">Back</a>");
}
if (curPage >= 93) { // Replace with highest page number
// Last page, no 'next' link
document.write('<a href="#" class="disabled">Next</a>');
} else {
var nextPage = curPage+1;
document.write("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"goto('"+nextPage+".html')\">Next</a>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: why are you using an onclick handler?  Why not just put the nextPage variable in the href attribute?

Comment: i see your last question got closed but i have a solution for you, which i will post below:

Comment: Your problem is with your curPage variable.  You are replacing the entire page variable with an empty string.  See my answer below.  Xavier's answer also looks worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

can you use jQuery to do something of this nature?

```
    $('#next').click(function(e)
    {
       e.preventDefault()
       $('#currentPage).remove();

       $(#'yourDiv').load('2.html, function()
       {
         //more logic here
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably with your curPage variable.  Try this:

```
curPage = location.href.substring(location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
curPage = parseInt(curPage.replace(/([1-99]+)\.html/, '$1'));
```

I believe your replace function is replacing everything with an empty string.  This should replace the page with the number.

### Updated

See code above.  You need to get the page name from the URL before you use the replace function.

Forgot to put location.href in the first line.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  You need to use both lines of the code I gave.  It shouldn't affect the links' visibility.

Comment: Updated again.  I forgot to put location.href in the first line.  Hope that works.

Comment: still having problem with current page.. i think still that not found the curPage.

Comment: does your current page start with a number, like 2.html?  If so, the curPage variable should have a value of 2.

Comment: yes my current page is start with number. but that is 1.html.

Comment: Maybe there are other problems with your code then.  Could you show us a live example?  Maybe use jsfiddle.net?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5157/discussion-between-abdul-rauf-and-bozdoz)

Answer (score 0):

So firstly you make a directory lets say:

localhost/book/

Secondly add a few html documents in that directory (such as 1.html, 2.html, 3.html) paste in the following html

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="code.js"></script>

<a class="prev" href="#">Load Prev page</a>
<a class="next" href="#">Load Next page</a>
```

Create a javascript file called code.js in the root directory and paste the following code:

```
    $(function(){
    var _href = location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    var _url = location.pathname.split('/');
    var _length = _url.length;
    var _page = _url[_length - 1] + "";
    var _current = _page.split('.')[0];
    _current = parseInt(_current);
    $('a.next').click(function(){
        var request = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + '/' + _href + "/" + (_current + 1) + '.html';
        $.ajax({
            url: request,
            type:'HEAD',
            error: function()
            {
               // last page
            },
            success: function()
            {
                window.location = request;
            }
        });

    });

});
```